# Annual version of the word "eve"

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there such a thing as a “pre-anniversary”? Or a better word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51529/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pre-anniversary-or-a-better-word)

If "eve' means the day before or period before an event, is there a word or succinct phrase meaning one year to the day before an event?

Comment: I think _eve of the anniversary_ is the closest you'll get.

Comment: The year before? The penultimate year? The year -to the day- is included in 'year'.

Comment: This might not help, but this question was asked a few months ago:  [Is there such a thing as a “pre-anniversary”? Or a better word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51529/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pre-anniversary-or-a-better-word)

Comment: @cornbreadninja  But wouldn't that mean the day before the anniversary?

Comment: @Danielδ, I suppose _anniversary of the eve_ is more appropriate.

Comment: But that means a year after the day before the event.  I think the OP is asking about a year before the event, e.g. if the event is March 30, 2012, then the [blank] is March 30, 2011.